# Allowed file extensions for a Windows RT Application

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

For my Windows Runtime Metro-Application written in c#, I want to use an own file format. For this file format I want to use an own file extension. In the package manifest I have declared the desired extension as a “File Type Association” and all works fine.

My question is, if there are some rules or limitations for assigning/using a file extension. I clearly would not use a commonly used file extension such as “.exe”, “.cab”, or “.docx”. But are there any accessible guidelines, recommendations or rules, on how file extensions have to be built (3 chars, 4 chars, …) and which file extensions never should be used. Or even does exists a Microsoft-service where file-types have to be registered to be accepted later on in the app store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some generic [best practices around file associations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144156%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#web_service_signup).  One relevant part ...

> Do Not Use Short File Name Extensions
>
> Long file name extensions offer the following advantages:
>
> The limited length of short extensions make them prone to extension
>   collisions. An extension collision occurs when the same extension is
>   used to classify multiple file types. Using long extensions
>   significantly decreases the chances of a collision. Short file names
>   tend to be somewhat cryptic. Long extensions tend to be more
>   meaningful because additional information can be embedded in the
>   extension.

For Metro style apps, the only limit I could find is in [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452684.aspx) ...

> Important note:  Here is an alphabetic list of file type names that
>   you cannot enter into the package manifest because they are either
>   reserved or forbidden: Accountpicture-ms, Appx, application,
>   Appref-ms, Bat, Cer, Chm, Cmd, Com, Cpl, crt, dll, drv, Exe, fon,
>   gadget, Hlp, Hta, Inf ,Ins, jse, lnk, Msi, Msp, ocx, pif, Ps1, Reg,
>   Scf, Scr, Shb, Shs, Sys, ttf, url, Vbe, Vbs, Ws, Wsc, Wsf, Wsh.

Comment: Also, you can check for collisions with other file extensions at http://www.fileinfo.com/